# Seeking a fast filter() with removal

Tags: python, performance, optimization, numpy

I'm trying to write a reasonably fast quicksort, but this has usage in many other applications.

The built in filter(function, iterable) function returns a list of the items in the iterable which when passed to the function return true, and is much faster than a traditional for loop when you only need to check one condition for one list.

What I am looking for is a function that is very fast (like filter) that will not only construct a new list, *but remove the items that it takes from the old list*. This would, in the application of single-pivot quicksort, allow for the removal of a filter statement and a likely near 2x speedup of the partition routine.

Is there such a function built in to python? What about with numpy? What's the fastest way to implement it if not?

For reference, here is the current partition code:

```
def partition(u):
    lesser = singleQuicksort(filter(lambda num: num <= u[0], u[1:]))
    greater = singleQuicksort(filter(lambda num: num > u[0], u[1:]))
    return lesser, greater
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a boolean mask:

```
def partition(u):
    mask = u[1:] <= u[0]
    return u[1:][mask], u[1:][~mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

In `numpy`, sort-of. That's array indexing. Considering the following case when you want to 'filter' out `inf`:

```
a=array([1,2,3,4,inf])
a[isfinite(a)]
```

or values smaller than 3

```
a=array([1,2,3,4,5])
a[a>3]
```

why 'sort-of'? Because indexing still creates a new array:

```
>>> a=array([1,2,3,4,inf])
>>> a[isfinite(a)]
array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.])
>>> id(a)
40165288 #your result will differ
>>> id(a[1])
40253288
>>> id(a[isfinite(a)][1])
39747512
>>> a[1]
2.0
>>> a[isfinite(a)][1]
2.0
```

Comment: Well, I still want the filtered out things returned. In quicksort, this would be implemented as filtering out items larger than the pivot and returning them to a list called greater, then assigning the remainder to a list called lesser. That's basically what I am trying to do here.